# after Onclick on start activity ..white screen appears or the app goes to the starting activity not the next or else crashes

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

this main activity FindDoctorDetails  cardview which is supposed to take me to next activity which is DoctorDetailsActivity

```
package com.example.healthcare;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class FindDoctorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_doctor);


      CardView exit = findViewById(R.id.cardFDBack);
      exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              startActivity(new Intent(FindDoctorActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
          }
      });

      CardView familyphysician = findViewById(R.id.cardFDFamilyPhysician);
      familyphysician.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent it = new Intent(FindDoctorActivity.this,DoctorDetailsActivity.class);
              it.putExtra("title", "Family Physicians");
              startActivity(it);
          }
      });

        CardView dietician = findViewById(R.id.cardFDDietician);
        dietician.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it = new Intent(FindDoctorActivity.this,DoctorDetailsActivity.class);
                it.putExtra("title", "Dietician");
                startActivity(it);
            }
        });

        CardView surgeon = findViewById(R.id.cardFDSurgeon);
        familyphysician.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it = new Intent(FindDoctorActivity.this,DoctorDetailsActivity.class);
                it.putExtra("title", "Surgeon");
                startActivity(it);
            }
        });

        CardView cardiologist = findViewById(R.id.cardFDCardiologist);
        cardiologist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it = new Intent(FindDoctorActivity.this,DoctorDetailsActivity.class);
                it.putExtra("title", "Cardiologist");
                startActivity(it);
            }
        });

        CardView dentist = findViewById(R.id.cardFDDentist);
        dentist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it = new Intent(FindDoctorActivity.this,DoctorDetailsActivity.class);
                it.putExtra("title", "Denstist");
                startActivity(it);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

after clicking on that FindDoctorActivity i am supposed to go to this  DoctorDetailsActivity but instead i get reloaded back to the FindDoctorActivity or just get a white screen and app crashes i am using an Api 33 and android studio latest flamingo

```
 package com.example.healthcare;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DoctorDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[][] doctor_details1 =
            {
                    {"Doctor Name : Ajit Saste", "Hospital Address : pimpri","Mobile No. : 1234567890","500"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Prasad Pawar", "Hospital Address : Nigdi","Mobile No. : 1234567809","600"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Swapnil Kale", "Hospital Address : Pune","Mobile No. : 1234567089","700"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Deepak Deshmukh", "Hospital Address : Chinchwad","Mobile No. : 1234560789","800"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Ashok Panda", "Hospital Address : Katraj","Mobile No. : 1234567890","900"}

            };
    private String[][] doctor_details2 =
            {
                    {"Doctor Name : Ankur Kar", "Hospital Address : pimpri","Mobile No. : 1234567890","500"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Anusha Gokhale", "Hospital Address : Nigdi","Mobile No. : 1234567809","600"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Dipa Rout", "Hospital Address : Pune","Mobile No. : 1234567089","700"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Aalok Krish", "Hospital Address : Chinchwad","Mobile No. : 1234560789","800"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Abhiram Kothari", "Hospital Address : Katraj","Mobile No. : 1234567890","900"}

            };
    private String[][] doctor_details3 =
            {
                    {"Doctor Name : Madhur Bhargav", "Hospital Address : pimpri","Mobile No. : 1234567890","500"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Advaith Kapur", "Hospital Address : Nigdi","Mobile No. : 1234567809","600"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Shaurya Nzareth", "Hospital Address : Pune","Mobile No. : 1234567089","700"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Sudarshan Gopal", "Hospital Address : Chinchwad","Mobile No. : 1234560789","800"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Aruna Upadhyay", "Hospital Address : Katraj","Mobile No. : 1234567890","900"}

            };
    private String[][] doctor_details4 =
            {
                    {"Doctor Name : Rajesh Kade", "Hospital Address : pimpri","Mobile No. : 1234567890","500"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Varsha Chaudhari", "Hospital Address : Nigdi","Mobile No. : 1234567809","600"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Anah Dalal", "Hospital Address : Pune","Mobile No. : 1234567089","700"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Gauri Lad", "Hospital Address : Chinchwad","Mobile No. : 1234560789","800"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Nima Jayram", "Hospital Address : Katraj","Mobile No. : 1234567890","900"}

            };
    private String[][] doctor_details5 =
            {
                    {"Doctor Name : Manas Mannan", "Hospital Address : pimpri","Mobile No. : 1234567890","500"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Kavika Ramesh", "Hospital Address : Nigdi","Mobile No. : 1234567809","600"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Minali Saraff", "Hospital Address : Pune","Mobile No. : 1234567089","700"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Rashmi Chander", "Hospital Address : Chinchwad","Mobile No. : 1234560789","800"},
                    {"Doctor Name : Neel Salvi", "Hospital Address : Katraj","Mobile No. : 1234567890","900"}

            };


    TextView tv;
    Button btn;
    String[][] doctor_details = {};
    HashMap<String, String> item;
    ArrayList list;
    SimpleAdapter sa;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_details);

        tv =  findViewById(R.id.textViewDDTitle);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonDDBack);

        Intent it = getIntent();
        String title = it.getStringExtra("title");
        tv.setText(title);

        if(title.compareTo("Family Physicians")==0)
            doctor_details = doctor_details1;
        else
        if(title.compareTo("Dietician")==0)
            doctor_details = doctor_details2;
        else
            if(title.compareTo("Surgeon")==0)
            doctor_details = doctor_details3;
        else
            if(title.compareTo("Dentist")==0)
            doctor_details = doctor_details4;
        else
            doctor_details = doctor_details5;



        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(DoctorDetailsActivity.this,FindDoctorActivity.class));
            }
        });

        list = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0;i<doctor_details.length;i++){
            item = new HashMap<String,String>();
            item.put("line1", doctor_details[i][0]);
            item.put("line2", doctor_details[i][1]);
            item.put("line3", doctor_details[i][2]);
            item.put("line4", doctor_details[i][3]);
            item.put("line5","Cons Fees :"+doctor_details[i][4]+"/-");
            list.add( item );
        }
         sa = new SimpleAdapter(this,list,
                 R.layout.multi_lines,
                 new String[]{"line1","line2","line3","line4","line5"},
                 new int []{R.id.line_a,R.id.line_b,R.id.line_c,R.id.line_d,R.id.line_e});
         ListView lst = findViewById(R.id.listViewDD);
         lst.setAdapter(sa);




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure, that DoctorDetailsActivity is added to your **Manifest.xml** file. It should be present in the **application** section:

```
<application
    <activity
        android:name=".DoctorDetailsActivity"
        android:exported="false"
    </activity>
</application>
```

Your DoctorDetailsActivity activity is apparently in the main branch of your project, so above declaration is fine. But if you would like to add activities that are in some subdirectories (i.e. in dir1/dir2/DoctorDetailsActivity), just add it like this:

```
<application
    <activity
        android:name=".dir1.dir2.DoctorDetailsActivity"
        android:exported="false"
    </activity>
</application>
```

I set **exported** as false as you obviously do not want this activity to be started from outside your app - you assume that Bundle is non-empty, and there is some Title key with some non-empty value present - you do not consider empty string.

Another thing is that you missed setting OnClickListener for the **surgeon** variable in FindDoctorActivity. Instead you overwrite familyphysician' OnClickListener (probably copy+pate mistake). With that, clicking on surgeon will have no effect, as no OnClickListener is defined - you will stay on FindDoctorActivity. If you haven't added DoctorDetailsActivity to your manifest, attempt to click all other doctors will crash your app.

Comment: thank you so much for you but the problem is still occurring done everything u said

Comment: Could you please share what is the crash reason in Run console? Click on Run tab in the bottom to check it. The crash is usually highlighted in red. If you do not see the Run tab, please press Alt+4 (for macos cmd+4).